# Can we send json data as part of custom metrics using open telemetry sdk to Otel collector?

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, otel

Example json

{
"StudentName": "John",
"StudentID": "1234",
"TimeStamp": "20200714",
}

I am researching on how I can proceed with adding custom metrics for json data using open telemetry sdk and then send it to Otel collector.Any suggestions here is much appreciated.